# Daylight savings time in java

Tags: java, timezone, dst

My requirement is create a combo with all time zone IDs that adjust with "Daylight Savings Time" (DST).

With `getAvailableIDs()` method I can have a list of timezoneIDs like [this](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/) but the problem is I don't know which one is adjust with DST and ones that do not.

So I leave my question here and looking for any suggestion or where can I find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate on the ids, retrieve the corresponding `TimeZone` and check [`useDaylightTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#useDaylightTime()) on it :

```
for (String tzId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId);
    if (tz.useDaylightTime()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Note:** depending on your use case, you may also want to check [`observesDaylightTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#observesDaylightTime()) which is a little bit different from [`useDaylightTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#useDaylightTime()).